# What does a sicpy.linalg.eig() returns when we pass two matrix in it ? Does it gives us the simultaneous diagonalization of the two matrix?

Tags: python, math, matrix, scipy, matrix-multiplication

#A and B are two square matrix with same shape
#Both are whiten i.e have correlation matrix as identity

m,n = scipy.linalg.eig(A,B)

#what does this will return what are m,n

Comment: check the documentation - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.linalg.eig.html

Comment: ... and check out the wikipedia description of the [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eigendecomposition_of_a_matrix#Generalized_eigenvalue_problem)